# how can i use conditional statements to switch colors of my heading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Button should toggle from original(black) to yellow and revert back. My issue is reverting it back. In the if-else statement only the else statement works. I have tried switch statement but that does not work
html

```js
var buttonElement = document.getElementById("title-button"); 
   var elementbutton = buttonElement;
   var elementsArray = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
   var element = elementsArray[0];

   elementbutton.addEventListener( "click", function(){
       if(elementbutton.hasOwnProperty("yellow")){
       element.remove("yellow");
       element.classList.remove("bordered-text");
       element.style.add = "black";
   } else {
       element.style.color = "yellow";
       element.classList.add("bordered-text");
   }
});
```

```css
.bordered-text{
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="title-button">Alters title</button>
<h1>Header 1</h1>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button you are clicking does not have any property named ***yellow***, thus `elementbutton.hasOwnProperty("yellow")` always evaluates to `false`, hence the *else* block is always executing.

Instead of checking the `hasOwnProperty` of the clicked button, you should check `element.style.color` of `h1`:

```js
var buttonElement = document.getElementById("title-button"); 
 var elementbutton = buttonElement;
 var elementsArray = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
 var element = elementsArray[0];

 elementbutton.addEventListener( "click", function(){
   if(element.style.color == "yellow"){
       element.style.color = "black";
       element.classList.remove("bordered-text");
   } else {
       element.style.color = "yellow";
       element.classList.add("bordered-text");
   }
 });
```

```css
.bordered-text{
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="title-button">Alters title</button>
<h1>Header 1</h1>
```